# Passing APEX objects to RemoteAction

Tags: javascript, javascript-remoting

I'm attempting to pass a JS array of JS Objects that are defined to match an sObject array (list) in my `@RemoteAction` method like so,

JS

```
var rateOverrides = [];
$('.modifiedRate').each(function(i,modifiedRateInput){
    if($(modifiedRateInput).val() !== ''){
        var baseRateId = $(modifiedRateInput).attr('id');
        console.log('Modified rate modified: '+baseRateId);

        // build RateOverride__c objects for overridden rates
        var rateOverride = { 'name' : $('#'+baseRateId+'-description').text(), 
                             'baseRate__c' : baseRateId,
                             //'customSchedule__c' : $('#customScheduleId'),
                             'customSchedule__c' : 'a18P0000002CLVcIAO',
                             'rate__c' : $(modifiedRateInput).val(),
                             'startDate__c' : $('#startDate').val()
                            };
        rateOverrides[i]= rateOverride;                             
        console.log(rateOverrides);
    }
});

RateListController.saveCustomScheduleOverrides(rateOverrides,function(result){
    console.log('saved!');
    $('#saving').hide();
});
```

And the corresponding `@RemoteAction`

```
global class RateListController {

...
    @RemoteAction
    global static Boolean saveCustomScheduleOverrides(RateOverride__c[] rateOverrides) 
    {
        system.debug(rateOverrides);
        return true;        
    }
}
```

I've checked, the object is correctly defined, yet I get the following when I attempt the callout:

```
Visualforce Remoting Exception: Unexpected type for RateListController.saveCustomScheduleOverrides(LIST<RateOverride__c>)
```

Comment: I'm assuming the use case is alot more complex, but if not it might be possible to use the Salesforce [ajax toolkit](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/ajax/)

Comment: I agree, this is too complex and should be more straight forward, unfortunately I don't think the ajax toolkit is my use-case

Comment: As I mentioned below, I've ultimately changed my approach and just used `JSON.stringify()` to serialize my JS object, pass it to the `@RemoteAction` as a string, and than deserialize in APEX. This was not ideal, and I thought that it would be possible to pass a JS object array directly to the remote method so long as it implemented the necessary fields it could be used to _create_ sObject records not just update them with an _id_ as the error message kept warning me I *needed to include an ID* I don't know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

TehNerd has an excellent post for this very thing.  He created an easy lightweight JavaScript library that allows you to easily perform DML calls from JavaScript.  I have used this a few times already and it saved me tons of time writing specific functions for all my custom objects.  It's a great post and an excellent library.  Should be perfect for what you need.

Check it out here

http://www.tehnrd.com/introducing-sobject-remote-for-visualforce-javascript-remoting/

Comment: THe key takeaway I got from reading his source is that the attributes property on any javascript object must be setup correctly for it to deserialize into an SObject automatically.

Comment: link is dead now....

Answer (score 1):

I think instead of constructing JSON, we can define a JS function with variables exactly same as a Sobject and add the sobject fields like below

```
 function RateOverride__c(){
this.name = null;
this.baseRate__c  = null;
this.customSchedule__c = null;
this.rate__c = null;
this.startDate__c = null;}
```

instead of this

```
var rateOverride = { 'name' : $('#'+baseRateId+'-description').text(), 
                         'baseRate__c' : baseRateId,
                         //'customSchedule__c' : $('#customScheduleId'),
                         'customSchedule__c' : 'a18P0000002CLVcIAO',
                         'rate__c' : $(modifiedRateInput).val(),
                         'startDate__c' : $('#startDate').val()
                        };
    rateOverrides[i]= rateOverride;
```

We can  construct the Array with Sobjects like below

```
 var rateOverrideArray = [];
 var rateOverride  = new RateOverride__c();
 rateOverride .name  = $('#'+baseRateId+'-description').text();
 rateOverrideArray.push(rateOverride);
```

We can pass above array as parameter in the Remoting save action , which will be collected in the controller method. I did similar stuff, for me its working with out errors.

Comment: This was an interesting suggestion, but I unfortunately encountered some of the same problems. I've ultimately decided to use `JSON.stringify(...)` and pass that and deserialize it. Though passing a regular JS object array shouldn't be an issue should it?